# Akka Java API - how to extend AbstractActor with logging AND with stash?

Tags: java, akka

In Scala I see that you can write something like this:

```
class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with Stash
```

In the Java API I see the following classes to extend

```
AbstractActor
AbstractLoggingActor
AbstractActorWithStash
```

Is there a way to create the Java equivalent of the Scala line above?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with Stash
```

`Actor`, `ActorLogging`, and `Stash` here are traits. In Scala, a class can extend a trait and mix in additional traits.

```
AbstractActor
AbstractLoggingActor
AbstractActorWithStash
```

The above classes in Akka's Java API are abstract classes. In Java, a class cannot extend more than one abstract class. Therefore, one cannot define in Java the syntactic equivalent of the `MyActor` class.

However, one can easily define the effective equivalent of `MyActor` in Java. `AbstractLoggingActor` is a convenient means to obtain a `LoggingAdapter` in an actor; the alternative to using `AbstractLoggingActor` is simply to manually create a `LoggingAdapter`. The following defines an actor that has both logging and stashing with the Java API:

```
import akka.actor.*;
import akka.event.Logging;
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter;

class MyActorInJava extends AbstractActorWithStash {
  LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().getSystem(), this);
  ...
}
```